# How to get data from multiple third-party APIs on one button click in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I have a web application where user needs to search an item from lists of data returned by multiple third-party APIs. Number of APIs may vary between 3 to 7 calls, maybe more.

How to call multiple third-party APIs on one click considering good performance so I can search an item in retrieved data from apis?

Any good article or toturial would be great.

Comment: You would add a controller, call to it. Your controller would probably inject a service you create that would be capable of doing the search. That service would inject `IHttpClientFactory` and use that to create `HttpClient` objects that would make the actual request.

Comment: Thank you @Andy much appreciated